# node_modules/rxjs/ BehaviorSubject has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular services and I got an error which is caused by `BehaviorSubject`.

**Error**

> Module '"ng5/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: `import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: @Vikas great the error went away! could you explain what is that, please?!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

if you want to import all `RxJS` just do :

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
```

If you only need `BehaviorSubject` :

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';
```

**EDIT : Explication**

On ES6 / TypeScript all `import` is related to `export` keyword. If you go on `node_modules/rxjs/index.d.ts` you will see all exported Class.

This means what ever see as exported on this file can be imported as : `import { SomeThing } from 'rxjs';`

But, your generated bundle file will inclure all RxJS stuff including unnecessary part of this library.

To avoid that, i recommand you to import from : `from 'rxjs/internal/SomeThing'` (replace SomeThing by what you need)

For operators, you can find it on `from 'rxjs/internal/operators/SomeThing'`

Comment: If something is marked as internal then I always get the impression that it was not intended to be used by external users of the library. Is there some kind of official documentation from RxJS that endorses these internal imports?

Comment: i have tested on both v11 and v12, what is your facing issue ?